# Iteratively return matches among three data frames using nested criteria

Tags: r, for-loop, match

I have the following three data frames:

```
df1<- structure(list(plot = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), lepsp = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 5L), .Label = c("lepA", "lepB", "lepC", "lepD", 
"lepE"), class = "factor"), count = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 3L)), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, -6L))

df2<-structure(list(plot = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), plantsp = structure(c(12L, 13L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 11L), .Label = c("H", 
"I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "O", "P", "Q", "S", "U", "X", "Y", "Z"
), class = "factor"), leafArea = c(1L, 5L, 5L, 10L, 20L, 11L, 
12L, 8L, 1L, 5L, 10L, 15L, 20L, 12L, 13L, 2L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-16L))

df3<-structure(list(lepsp = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 5L), .Label = c("lepA", "lepB", "lepC", "lepD", 
"lepE"), class = "factor"), plantsp = structure(c(6L, 7L, 8L, 
6L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 6L, 8L, 8L, 1L), .Label = c("S", "T", 
"U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-13L))
```

Essentially I need to iterate through `df1` for unique subsets based on two factor levels. Upon each iteration, I need to find matches between `df1` and `df2` for a particular column. Among the matches found between `df2` and `df1`, I need to take that subset of rows in `df2` and find matches with `df3` based on a separate set of criteria and return rows that match for a different factor. To summarize, specific to the data frames posted above:

1. For each ith `df1$plot` and jth  `df1$lepsp`, subset rows in `df2`  for those entries in  `df1$plot` and `df2$plot` that match. Similarly and secondly,   subset rows in `df3`  for those entries in  `df1$lepsp` and `df3$lepsp` that match.
2. Among the subsetted `df2` and `df3` from step 1 above, for those levels of `df3$plantsp` that are also in `df2$plantsp` return the matching rows in `df2`.
3. Return a data frame that indexes the associated ith `df1$plot` and jth `df1$lepsp` and the associated rows in `df2` that matched based on criteria found in step2
4. Iterate through all levels of `df1$lepsp` within each `df1$plot`.

The result output would be as follows:

```
result<- structure(list(plot = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L
), lepsp = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 5L
), .Label = c("lepA", "lepB", "lepC", "lepD", "lepE"), class = "factor"), 
lepcount = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 3L), plantsp = structure(c(3L, 
4L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 1L), .Label = c("S", "U", 
"X", "Y", "Z"), class = "factor"), leafarea = c(1L, 5L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 15L, 20L, 13L, 13L, 15L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

Given that this has such nested structure I struggle to think of a method that would work to put all parts together, however I know that the following functions may be useful:

```
for (i in unique(levels(df1$plot)){
 for( j in  unique(levels(df1$lepsp)){
 sub1<- df2[which(df1$plot %in% df2$plot),]
 sub2<- df3[which(df2$lepsp %in% df3$lepsp),]
 result <- data.frame(plot=unique(df1$plot),lepsp=unique(df1$lepsp),
                   plantsp=df2$plantsp,leafArea=df2$leafArea)}
 return(result)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could keep the datasets in a `list` and use `merge` with `Reduce`

```
out <- Reduce(function(...) merge(...), list(df1, df2, df3))
```

---

Or with `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
list(df1, df2, df3) %>%
      reduce(inner_join)
```

Comment: Voted for your solution! I guess a bit shorter base R version is `Reduce(merge,list(df1,df2,df3))` :P